# Как установить заголовок Content-Type в значение application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: php, curl, keycloak

Я хочу сделать авторизацию пользователя с помощью keycloak, отправляю запрос на получение `access_token`, но получаю ошибку `Missing form parameter: grant_type`, что означает отсутствие правильного заголовка `Content-Type` (нужно значение `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Код

```php
    public function login(Request $req) {
        $url = env('KEYCLOAK_HOST').'/auth/realms/'.env('KEYCLOAK_REALM').'/protocol/openid-connect/token';
        $options = [
            'client_id' => env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'grant_type' => env('KEYCLOAK_GRANT_TYPE'),
            'username' => $req->username,
            'password' => $req->password,
            'scope' => 'openid'
        ];
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return response(['res' => json_decode($response), 'err' => json_decode($error)], 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
```

Как я могу правильно установить заголовок `Content-Type` в значение `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Вы зачем-то путаете заголовок **ответа** с заголовком запроса, и в результате задаёте бессмысленный вопрос, который потом будет засорять интернет

Comment: @Ипатьев, перепутал, исправил, спасибо

Comment: Чтобы видеть исходящие заголовки в curl_getinfo, надо добавить CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно дело в этом:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
Примечание: При передаче массива CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS данные будут закодированы как multipart/form-data, а при передаче строки в кодировке URL-адреса данные будут закодированы как application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Если я правильно понял для application/x-www-form-urlencoded нужно убрать:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
```

Филды подать вида:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($options));
```